# Determine if Riemann integrable and evaluae the integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x):=2$ if $0\leq x <1$, $f(1)=3$ and $f(x):=1$ if $1<x\leq 2$. Show that $f\in R[0,2]$ and evaluate the integral.

I know what the graph looks like, I'm having a hard time figuring out the integral.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Your function is Riemann integrable over $[0,2]$ as [a step function](http://facstaff.cbu.edu/wschrein/media/M414%20Notes/M414C7.pdf). We have
$$
\int_0^2h(x)dx=\int_0^1h(x)dx+\int_1^2h(x)dx=\int_0^12dx+\int_1^21dx
$$